# How to parse JSON array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, each

**EDIT** I checked the jQuery documentation and using $.ajax with the json datatype specified returns an evaluated javascript object, so eval() isn't the answer here.  I knew that anyway, since I am able to parse single JSON objects, just not arrays.  The problem is the $.each-ing my way through them :)

I have followed the syntax for parsing a JSON array in jQuery to the letter, but it doesn't work for some reason.  I am fetching the array using $.ajax, have specified the correct datatype, and in Firebug can see that the response from my PHP script is [].  Yet when I try to use $.each to iterate through the array, all I get is undefined values when I try to console.log various parts of the array.  Here is where my php script makes and encodes the array:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($new_res) > 0) {
$messages = array();

while($message_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_res)) {
  $message = array(
    'poster' => $message_data['poster'],
    'message' => $message_data['message'],
    'time' => $message_data['time']
  );

  $messages[] = $message;
}

echo json_encode($messages);
} else if(mysqli_num_rows($new_res) == 0) {
$message = array(
  'poster' => '',
  'message' => 'No messages!',
  'time' => 1
);

echo json_encode($message);
}
```

And here is my attempt to parse it:

```
   var logged_in = '<?php echo $logged_in; ?>';
   var poster = '<?php echo $_SESSION["poster"];?>';
     $.ajax({
     url: 'do_chat.php5',
     type: 'post',
     data: ({'poster':poster,'logged_in':logged_in}),
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(messageIndex, message) {
                    console.log(parseInt($('#chatWindow :last-child > span').html())+' '+message['time']);
       if((parseInt(message['time']) > parseInt($('#chatWindow :last-child > span').html()))) {
     $('#chatWindow').append('<div class="poster">'+message['poster']+'</div><div class="message"><span>'+message['time']+'</span>'+message['message']+'</div>');
       }
       });
     }
     });
```

Without the $.each function I am able to successfully parse single JSON objects, but not an array.  This is my first outing with JSON and $.each, and I'm pretty new to jQuery, so go easy if my code has ugly bits!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? If so I suggest selecting an answer :p

Comment: I didn't yet, no.  I edited but got no further replies.  The problem either lies with the way PHP is encoding the JSON object or with the $.each syntax.  I console.logged the response data, and then eval()-ed it and console logged it and I get the same thing, so eval was not the answer.

Answer (score 13):

No, with `eval` is not safe, you can use JSON parser that is much safer: `var myObject = JSON.parse(data);`
For this use the lib https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: From the JSON page: `The eval function is very fast. However, it can compile and execute any JavaScript program, so there can be security issues`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is pretty long after your post, but wanted to post for others who might be experiencing this issue and stumble across this post as I did.

It seems there's something about jquery's `$.each` that changes the nature of the elements in the array.

I wanted to do the following:

```
$.getJSON('/ajax/get_messages.php', function(data) {

    /* data: 

    [{"title":"Failure","details":"Unsuccessful. Please try again.","type":"error"},
    {"title":"Information Message","details":"A basic informational message - Please be aware","type":"info"}]

    */

    console.log ("Data0Title: " + data[0].title);
    // prints "Data0Title: Failure"

    console.log ("Data0Type: " + data[0].type);
    // prints "Data0Type: error"

    console.log ("Data0Details: " + data[0].details);
    // prints "Data0Details: Unsuccessful. Please try again"


    /* Loop through data array and print messages to console */

});
```

To accomplish the loop, I first tried using a jquery `$.each` to loop through the data array. However, as the OP notes, this doesn't work right:

```
$.each(data, function(nextMsg) {    
    console.log (nextMsg.title + " (" + nextMsg.type + "): " + nextMsg.details);
    // prints 
    // "undefined (undefined): undefined
    // "undefined (undefined): undefined
});
```

This didn't exactly make sense since I am able to access the `data[0]` elements when using a numeric key on the data array. So since using a numerical index worked, I tried (successfully) replacing the `$.each` block with a for loop:

```
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    console.log (data[i].title + " (" + data[i].type + "): " + data[i].details);
    // prints
    // "Failure (error): Unsuccessful. Please try again"
    // "Information Message (info): A basic informational message - Please be aware"
}
```

So I don't know the underlying problem, a basic, old fashioned javascript for loop seems to be a functional alternative to jquery's `$.each`

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) - new in jQuery 1.4.1

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to parse JSON data returned from an ajax call, and the following is working for me:

Sample PHP code

```
$portfolio_array= Array('desc'=>'This is test description1','item1'=>'1.jpg','item2'=>'2.jpg');

echo json_encode($portfolio_array);
```

And in the .js, i am parsing like this:

```
var req=$.post("json.php", { id: "" + id + ""},
function(data) {
    data=$.parseJSON(data);
    alert(data.desc);
    $.each(data, function(i,item){
    alert(item);
    });
})
.success(function(){})
.error(function(){alert('There was problem loading portfolio details.');})
.complete(function(){});
```

If you have multidimensional array like below

```
$portfolio_array= Array('desc'=>'This is test description 1','items'=> array('item1'=>'1.jpg','item2'=>'2.jpg'));
echo json_encode($portfolio_array);
```

Then the code below should work:

```
var req=$.post("json.php", { id: "" + id + 
    function(data) {
    data=$.parseJSON(data);
    alert(data.desc);
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
    alert(item);
    });
})
.success(function(){})
.error(function(){alert('There was problem loading portfolio details.');})
.complete(function(){});
```

Please note the sub array key here is items, and suppose if you have `xyz` then in place of `data.items` use `data.xyz`

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET 3.5 **FIX**

All of you are slightly wrong, but the combination of all of your efforts has paid off!

Instead of eval('([' + jsonData + '])'); do

```
success: function(msg){
var data = eval(msg.d);
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data[i].parametername /// do whatever you want here.
};
```

I don't know anything about the whole "don't use eval," but what I do know is that by doing the '([' + msg + '])' you are nesting those objects deeper, instead of up a level.

Answer (score 1):

Careful with the eval, the JSON specs http://json.org/js.html recommend something like

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

And there may be some more gotchas. There is a plugin for jQuery that will take care of it, i guess:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is a string of `'[{}]'` at that point in time, you can `eval` it like so:

```
function(data) {
    data = eval( '(' + data + ')' )
}
```

However this method is far from secure, this will be a bit more work but the best practice is to parse it with Crockford's JSON parser: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Another method would be `$.getJSON` and you'll need to set the `dataType` to json for a pure jQuery reliant method.

Comment: Does this not only work if the array that php jason_encodes is a single level array? For example, see the original code that generates the JSON object.  Only in the event that the database query generates no results is the array one-dimensional, otherwise it is multidimensional.

Comment: oh I didn't see that part.. hm

Comment: Ok - you should still be evaluating it, it's now a string at that point in your code I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript eval() function to parse the JSON for you. See [the JSON website](http://json.org/js.html) for a better explanation, but you should be able to change your success function to...

```
var returnedObjects = eval(data);
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < returnedObjects.length; i++){
    console.log('Time: ' + returnedObjects[i].time);
}
```

...or something close.

Comment: I think that is effectively what $.each is supposed to do, and I thought using $.ajax with a json datatype meant that the response data came pre-eval-ed.  I will try it though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download a JSON parser from a [link on the JSON.org website](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) which works great, you can also stringify you JSON to view the contents.

Also, if you're using EVAL and it's a JSON array then you'll need to use the following synrax:

`eval('([' + jsonData + '])');`

Answer (score -1):

Do NOT eval. use a real parser, i.e., from json.org